# How to find minimum and maximum of the numbers you input without arrays ? (simple)

Tags: java, max, java.util.scanner, min

I have this assignment and I am stuck, please help, I'm sure it'll be quick. Please help!

This is my prompt:
Write a method minMax( ) that has a int type parameter that represents how many integers you want to enter. It will input that many integers and will print the minimum and maximum values among the entered values.

minMax(5) will input 5 integer values and print the minimum and maximum values of the entered values.

I've tried to check the questions related to my topic, however, they were far too complicated. This is simple code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //call your method here 

   }
  public static int minMax(int num){
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
   int num = scan.nextInt();
   int min = num;
   int max = num;
   for(int i = 1; i < ; i++){

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Compare each input to a pre-existing result

Comment: Hint One: Don't redefine `num` in your method. Hint Two: Make the method `void`; what `int` would you return? Hint Three: Initialize `min` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` Hint Four: `for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)`

Answer (score -2):

Here is quick fix for you.

Please check following code to get min and max value from all element list.

**Input :**

Please enter value of N: 
5

Please enter 5 numbers

4

2

10

156

2

**Output :**

Max of N number is : 156

Min of N number is : 2

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Scanner scan = null;
        int n = 0;
        int max = 0,min = 0;
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter value of N: ");
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            n = scan.nextInt();
            max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            System.out.printf("Please enter %d numbers %n", n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int current = scan.nextInt();
                if (current > max) {
                    max = current;
                }
                if (current < min) {
                    min = current;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Max of N number is : " + max);
            System.out.println("Min of N number is : " + min);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
                scan.close();
        }
    }
```

Hope this solution works.

Please mark as answer if this solution helpful.

Comment: this answer is similar to ones ive seen before. is there a more ismple way to put it? i've also mentioned that there are no use of arrays.